# Probability to have the same number of positive outcomes after the same number of fair coin tosses.

Tags: probability

Andrew and Brian are sitting at the beach and each of them has 5 stones in front of him. Each guy starts tossing a fair coin and every time each of them gets a head, he throws one of his stones in the sea, otherwise he does nothing. What is the probability that both friends have thrown all their stones after the same number of tosses?

If H = heads and T = tails, the sequence of outcomes must be like this: (just an example)
Player A: T H T T H T T T H H T H
Player B: H T T H H T T T T H T H

i.e. they both finish after the same number of tosses.
Obviously the last toss is H for both (otherwise they would keep on tossing).
So we are looking for the probability of having such a series for both friends but I don't know how to continue.
Negative binomial distribution? But how can we apply it when we have two discrete players, whose coin tosses are independent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be the chance of both of them getting 4 H's in the first 4 flips followed by a H, plus the chance of both of them getting 4 H's out of the first 5 flips followed by a H plus ...

So that would be:

$${4\choose4}^2\cdot\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{10} + {5\choose4}^2\cdot\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{12} + .... $$

i.e.

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty {{4+n}\choose{4}}^2\cdot\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{10+2n}$$

[Wolphram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20((4%2Bn)%20choose%204)%5E2%20%2F%20(2%5E(10%2B2n)),%20n%3D0%20to%20infinity) says it is $\frac{1921}{19683}$, so it's a little under 10%

Comment: TeX-tip: You can make nice parentheses by writing \left( . \right). Also, a better-looking multiplication sign would be \times or \cdot.

Comment: @Lovsovs I'll try those immediately! Thanks :) ... Yeah, that came it much nicer, thanks again!

Comment: For combinations you can do {5 \choose 4} to get ${5 \choose 4}$ instead of composing it out of parentheses.  The \left( and \right) is handy when you want parentheses around complicated objects.  Also you can highlight text then click on the link symbol to embed the link.  The text will come out blue, so can say anything you want, and the link will be live.  For your example I would say something like Alpha shows this is \frac{1921}{19683} and have the Alpha be the link.  Looking good.

Comment: @RossMillikan  OK, thanks! Can't believe I never knew about the live link ...

Comment: To all: Thank you for your replies. Actually I read a paper on this game, which is called the M&M game. By reading it, I understood the logic and the reason why the formulas you wrote work. Great job guys!

Comment: @Samuel You're welcome! :)

Answer (score 1):

I may be slightly under-thinking this, but... 
First, find the probability that player 1 gets his first 5 coin tosses in N flips. This is negative binomial:

$ P(N) $= ${N-1}\choose{5-1}$ $.5^5 * .5^{N-5} $

Since the players are independent, P is the same for player 2. So the probability that they both end on N flips is $ P^2$.

To find the probability that they both end on the SAME number, regardless of what the number is, simply sum over all possible N (in this case, 5 to infinity):

$ P = \sum_5^\infty $(${N-1}\choose{5-1}$ $.5^5 * .5^{N-5} $)$^2$

Wolfram alpha tells me this sum comes out to 0.0976...

Comment: I'd appreciate if somebody could verify if my answer is correct, as I'm not 100% confident in it. Thank you

Comment: Yes, it is correct. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X_1$ ($X_2$) be the number of tosses that Andrew (Brian) makes until getting $5$ heads.

Then both $X_i$ follows a Negative Binomial distribution. Furthermore, they are independent.

You are interested in the event $E\equiv  X_1=X_2$.
Its probability can be computed as

$$P(E) = \sum_{x} P(E , X_1=x) = \sum_{x} P(E \mid X_1=x) P(X_1=x)=\sum_{x} P(X_2=x) P(X_1=x)$$

I think you can go on from here.

Answer (score 0):

Negative binomial distribution with parameters $r$ and $p$ is a distribution over the number of trials $n$ required to get $r$ successes when the success probability at each trail is $p$.

Now, in your case $r = 5$ and $p = 0.5$, and

$$P(X_i = n) = \binom{n-1}{r-1}p^r (1-p)^{n-r}, \, \, i\in\{1,2\}, n \geq r$$

The explanation behind the pmf is: Choose $r-1$ trials out of first $n-1$ which had success and the last trail i.e. $n$th trial had a success.

Since $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent,

$$P(X_1=X_2) = \sum_{n=5}^{\infty}P(X_1=n)P(X_2=n)$$